# Why does quartz don't restart the jobs?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am doing a web application, use Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE + quartz 1.8.6, and MySQL 5.5 is used to store the scheduling information. When I restart the tomcat, the quartz has been restarted, but it doesn't rerun jobs. For example, I have a job to print "aaa" 10 times, and I restarted the tomcat after it has run 3 times, the remaining 7 times will not be done. 
Below is the spring configure file, all the jobs and triggers will created by user, so there is only one bean.

```
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
lazy-init="false"></bean>
```

Below is the quartz.properties.

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = false

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate  
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_  
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false  
# Configure Datasources 
#============================================================================ 
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz1x?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8 
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = root 
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password =111111
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 10
```

Spring indected the Scheduler, and below is the code

```
        JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("jName","gName", NewJob.class);
        SimpleTrigger simpleTrigger = new SimpleTrigger("jName1","gName1");
        simpleTrigger.setStartTime(new Date());
        simpleTrigger.setRepeatInterval(3000);
        simpleTrigger.setRepeatCount(10);

        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, simpleTrigger);
```

NewJob.java

```
public class NewJob implements Job {

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println(new Date());
}

}
```

If I don't use spring, but servlet(org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet), there is no problem.

Comment: Show scheduling information?  If you restart tomcat, you restart your application, then you are restarting quartz.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not good at English, are you mean the codes? I have added codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring does not read quartz.properties default, you should write the config file in the bean just like below.

```
    <bean id="scheduler"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
    lazy-init="false">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties" />
    </bean>
```